# Weird issues after upgrading to Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, ethernet, windows-11-upgrade

I recently upgraded to Windows 11 and I have noticed some problems that I didn't have before.

Firstly, Xbox and Powershell automatically start after logging in. I have tried disabling them in startup app settings but the option seems to be greyed out/blocked. I have also tried using Task Manager to disable them but Task Manager is reporting that the apps are already disabled.

Secondly, my Ethernet seems to disconnect from the internet after about 3 to 7 minutes. Replugging the cable fixes the problem for another 3 to 7 minutes after which it disconnects again. Wi-Fi is working fine.

I did not have any of these issues prior to upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 11 and I have noticed these issues immediately after upgrading. I still have the option to revert back to Windows 10 as I have not yet deleted the old installation files.

Edit: Powershell doesn't run a script. Powershell simply starts and opens in terminal mode without any script running.

Comment: Xbox is a UWP application which status (running or suspended) will be restored. Be sure to quit the Xbox application if you don’t want it to automatically be running. We would need more information on what PowerShell script is being ran to solve that particular issue. The first thing I would do is increase the time to rollback before you are unable to do so. Editing your question to include the necessary information to solve your issues would be the next step.

Comment: Re: XBox -- **If** you do not use it, disable *most* of the XBox services in *services.msc*. To disable all, you'll need to do so in the Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<servicename>` by taking ownership from *TrustedInstaller*. On this PC, I've done so without issue.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11 does not always work.

When it does not work, and assuming your computer is Windows 11 capable, then the best approach (my experience) is to back up all your documents and reinstall Windows 11 fresh.

After installing Windows 11 pay attention to and upgrade old 32-bit apps to their 64-bit counterparts.

Pay particular attention to upgrading apps with shell context extensions (WinMerge and like). Use Nirsoft Shell View to help find these.

Finally, if not Windows 11 capable (PC Health Check), revert to Windows 10 and stay with Windows 10 until you can get a new computer.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not had those particular issues, I have seen several strange ones like those when users perform the "Windows Update" upgrade from 10 to 11.

A common one I've found was windows Taskbar blanking out (icon cache fix:negative) or just plain not being there at all.

A couple of them, just checking/applying additional updates, in the advanced options section of windows update panel, did the trick.

In another case, rolling back the upgrade to windows 10 and then performing a manual "in-place" upgrade with the windows update assistant worked well.

In the last case, already mentioned, rolling back to windows 10 until a clean install of latest Win11 or new pc was the fix.

Best wishes, hope one of the former ones work for you!